# Poisson's equation and Fourier transform.

Tags: poissons-equation

Is it possible to solve the Poisson's equation with the Fourier transform?

Let
\begin{align}
-\partial_x^2 u(x)=f(x),\quad x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align}
then $u(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\xi^2}\widehat{f}(\xi)\right)$?

Comment: If $u$ is defined on the whole real line with suitable boundary conditions at infinity then probably. The domain and boundary conditions are crucial to the solution process though. On a finite interval Fourier series come into play and on the half line Laplace transform